# I need the script to work on all dav files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, file-conversion

Script should run in recursive mode, find DAV files and start DAV to JPG conversions using FFMPEG. The script is working, identifying files in folders and starting conversions when DAV files exist, but is ignoring some DAV files.
When I put these DAV files back in the folder it converts correctly.
What could be wrong?
I thought it might be the speed of the process, since the files are being generated in the folder, the script must wait for the file to be closed and complete to act. I tried to delay the conversion process by 15 seconds using a PING, but it still skips some files.

```
cd E:\VM01\1002
MD "E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\SNAPSHOT 1002"
MD  "E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\PROCESSED 1002" 

:LOOP01  
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 10 -w 6000 >NUL     
For /R %%G in (*.Dav) do IF NOT EXIST "%%G" GOTO SKIP01

:LOOP02
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 10 -w 6000 >NUL    
For /R %%G in (*.Dav) do IF EXIST "%%G" GOTO SKIP02
REM ALL THIS WILL BE DONE IF THE DAV FILE EXISTS
:
:
:SKIP01
REM 6 SECONDS OF DELAY ...
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 10 -w 6000 >NUL
GOTO LOOP01
:
:
:SKIP02
REM START CONVERSION
PING 1.1.1.1  -n 10 -w 15000 >NUL
For /R %%G in (*.Dav) do IF EXIST "%%G" ffmpeg -i "%%G" -r 0.2 -bt 20M -s 480x300 "%%~nG"%%06d.jpg
for /r %%G in (*.Dav) do Move "%%G" "E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\PROCESSED 1002"
Move "*.jpg" "E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\SNAPSHOT 1002" 
PING 1.1.1.1  -n 10 -w 3000 >NUL
)
GOTO LOOP01
```

Comment: The section labelled `:SKIP02` has unbalanced parentheses. _I have formatted your code to better highlight it!_

Comment: I'm going to assume that the `.Dav` files are being generated from one or more other processes. The main issue, that I can see is that a `.Dav` file may exist when you perform the check, but at that time it may not be a fully formed/completed file. If this is the case, your `FFmpeg` command will be unable to properly convert the incomplete file.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your script to work in the manner I think your posted example is supposed to, and subject to you running it on [windows-vista](/questions/tagged/windows-vista) or newer:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "DavTree=E:\VM01\1002"
Set "DavDone=E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\PROCESSED 1002"
Set "JpgDone=E:\COLETA SNAPSHOT\SNAPSHOT 1002"
CD /D "%DavTree%" || "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%DavDone%\" MD "%DavDone%" || "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%JpgDone%\" MD "%JpgDone%" || "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 1>NUL & GoTo :EOF

:ProcessDavs  
    "%__AppDir__%where.exe" /Q /R . *.Dav
    If ErrorLevel 1 "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 6 1>NUL & GoTo ProcessDavs
    For /F "Delims=" %%# In ('Dir /B /S /A:-D-S-L /O:D /T:W *.Dav') Do (
        "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 1>NUL
        "F:\ull\PathTo\FFmpeg.exe" -i "%%#" -r 0.2 -bt 20M -s 480x300 "%%~n#%%06d.jpg"
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 (Move /Y "%%#" "%DavDone%" 1>NUL
            Move /Y "%%~n#%%06d.jpg" "%JpgDone%" 1>NUL))
    GoTo ProcessDavs
```

Please note on line `15`, I have used `"F:\ull\PathTo\FFmpeg.exe"`, please adjust this to the correct location. *If located in `%PATH%` or `E:\VM01\1002`, you can edit it to just `FFmpeg.exe`, if your `%PATHEXT%` variable is unmodified, you can also remove the `.exe`, (I'm not recommending either)*. The issue I highlighted in the comments, does not form part of this answer, however, I have arranged the command to recurse the directories so that it picks up the least recently written `.dav` file first. This may give additional time for any files still being written to complete before you process them. You can also adjust the `6` second `timeout` on line `12` and `3` second `timeout` on line `14` as necessary, if the issue persists.

Comment: While the file does not complete FFmpeg does not start conversion. So I believe that is not the problem.
While the file is not complete, I see that ffmpeg does not convert as it appears "Permission Denied" and is released when it is 100% complete.
It always rejects are the same files (same names) already tried to remove the special characters from the file names but it still did not work.
I inserted this Ping thinking about delaying the processing because it could be taking too long to close the file after it is finished. But it was not like that.

Comment: Why have you waited two days since posting your initial question and a full day after my answer was posted to now explain that your issue is with filenames? Anyhow, that isn't relevant to my post above I haven't used `ping` and I have used code I am happy to debug, should it be problematic. Can you please run the script exactly as I have posted it above and subject to the first sentence of my footnote. If it works but leaves the same files behind, please post those filenames complete with all of their actual characters without anything removed or modified. We cannot debug it without your info.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I was absent. 
I tested this code, but it still doesn't work. I had to change some directories. 
Displays file or directory error with wrong name.
I will post in the comment the changes I need to make.